# Having difficulty figuring out what a call to an assembly function returns

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly language. I have the following assembly code:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.bits 32

.global asm0

asm0:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp,esp
    mov eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
    mov ebx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
    mov eax,ebx
    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp 
    ret
```

I want to figure out what the following command returns: 
asm0(0x2a,0x4f).

I am running Ubuntu, and I have already downloaded NASM. I've been reading about the syntax of Assembly code here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_basic_syntax.htm, but I cannot figure this out still. I have coded with C++ for three years, yet this is still confusing me. Could anyone with some more experience please help me figure this out?

EDIT: The code above says push and move, so it sort of looks like a stack data structure? Then it returns at the end. But, there are no parameters to this function. How would this work?

**Error message when running gcc -m32 -g main.c assembly.s**

```
myName@myName:~/Downloads$ gcc -m32 -g main.c file.S

main.c: In function ‘main’:

main.c:5:17: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘asm0’ [-Wimplicit-
function-declaration]

    printf("%d", asm0(123,456));
                 ^~~~

file.S: Assembler messages:

file.S:2: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.bits'
```

Comment: You can just try it, and single-step it with a debugger.  Unless it crashes because it destroys the caller's ebx (a call-preserved register according to the i386 System V calling convention.)

Comment: `push` operates on the call stack, not exactly a stack data structure.  http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html

Comment: Which debugger do you suggest I use? I am pretty much clueless on how to use NASM.

Comment: GDB is ok.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info. See the "calling convention" section of the x86 tag wiki to understand how asm functions get their args. 
 https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui also mostly ok for asm, if you want a GUI.

Comment: I can't get gdbgui to work. It keeps saying gdbgui command not found, after I install it. Is there any easier way to figure out the output of this code?

Comment: Maybe an online compiler or something?

Comment: Well obviously you can just printf the return value from C if you write a caller for it, or single-step it in regular GDB.  `gdb ./a.out`.  To understand how it works, you *definitely* want to single-step it in GDB and watch registers change.  `layout reg` and `si`.  Or you can read the linked duplicates to understand how args are passed in the i386 System V C calling convention

Comment: I am still very confused. The program that I have in my original post is in a file called "file.S"; is it possible to make this a .C file? I've searched for decompilers, but I think they are all paid?

Comment: You have the code for a *function*, not a whole program.  You should write a C program that calls it, like `int main(){printf("%d", asm0(123,456));}`, and `gcc -m32 -g main.c file.S`.

Comment: I am doing this, but I get the error message saying that I have an implicit declaration of the function asm0, as I never defined it in the C program, I believe. I updated the original post for your convenience.

Comment: I believe I need to do the declaration at the start of the C program. So it should be something like this?: int asm0(int, int);

EDIT: I tried this, and that warning message is gone. now, all I have is the "file.S:2: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.bits'" message

Comment: Yeah I left out `#include <stdio.h>` and a prototype for `int asm0(int,int);`.  I hadn't noticed that `.bits 32` isn't a valid GAS directive, so your function doesn't assemble.  Simply remove that line and it works fine if you compile with `gcc -no-pie -fno-pie -m32 main.c asm0.s`.  Turns out gcc does depend on the function not clobbering EBX if you make a PIE executable by default.  IDK where you got that code from, but the equivalent GAS directive is `.code32`.  (But you don't need that, `.code32` is already the default when assembling into a 32-bit object file.)

Comment: Okay, sorry for asking so many questions. I am very new to this. I'm getting an a.out file now, but it has many unreadable characters. Shouldn't it just be like one integer output or something? Also, I assume for my hexadecimal values, converting to integers for the sake of passing them into this program and then converting it back will be sufficient? Thank you so so much


// EDIT: using gcc -no-pie -fno-pie -m32 main.c file.s, I get an a.out executable file, which gives me "456" when I run it. is this correct ?

Comment: `a.out` is an executable.  You don't view its contents, you run it.  Or disassemble it with `objdump -drwC -Mintel a.out` to see the compiler-generated asm for `main`, or run `gdb ./a.out` and single step it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function looks for its 2 args on the stack, above the return address.  Notice the accesses to `[ebp+8]` and `[ebp+12]`, after setting up a traditional stack frame.

You don't declare args in asm; that's a high level concept that you *implement* yourself in the code in asm.

`push` operates on the call stack, not exactly a stack data structure. 
 https://felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html.  It just decreases ESP and stores to `[esp]`.  It's doing that to save/restore the caller's EBP as part of making a traditional stack frame.  This is super-basic stuff, read some more tutorials or guides if you haven't seen this yet.

---

You can easily just try the code and find what it does by calling it from a C program.

Except you can't because your asm won't assemble.  `.bits 32` is not a valid GAS directive, but this is pretty clearly GNU assembler (GAS) syntax otherwise.  I'm not aware of any assemblers that have a `.intel_syntax noprefix` directive other than GAS itself and clang's built-in assembler, and neither of them support `.bits 32`.  So I'm guessing this function was from a tutorial or something and was hand-ported to GAS from NASM syntax (`bits 32`) or something without actually testing. 
 But you don't need and shouldn't use that directive, or the GAS equivalent `.code32`.  32-bit code is already the default when assembling into a 32-bit object file, so `.code32` would let you assemble 32-bit code into a 64-bit object file if you just used `gcc foo.s` without `-m32`, and then you'd have hard-to-debug problems are runtime instead of an obvious error at assemble time.

**So remove the `.bits 32` line**, that solves the error message in the question.

To get rid of the warning messages, expand the one-liner I wrote in a comment by providing the proper headers and prototype.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int asm0(int,int);

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", asm0(123,456));
}
```

---

The function is also buggy: it clobbers `ebx`, which is a call-preserved register in the i386 System V calling convention.  (Like in all the normal x86 calling conventions.)

gcc on Linux distros that enable default-PIE makes code that depends on EBX being call-preserved, and actually crashes.  (you could still single-step it with a debugger, though, because the crash happens after `asm0` returns.)

But you can make an executable that happens to work and will let you just run it to see which arg it returns:

```
peter@volta:/tmp$ gcc -g -Og -no-pie -fno-pie -m32 main.c asm0.s 
peter@volta:/tmp$ ./a.out 
456
```

---

**`asm0` returns its 2nd arg (by copying it to EAX, the return-value register).  It loads it to EBX, then copies EBX to EAX, overwriting the result of loading the first arg.**

You can watch this happen with `gdb ./a.out`

```
(gdb)  layout reg
       b main
       r
       si
       (press return to single-step one instruction at a time through the code, including into your function)
```

GDB highlights which registers were changed on each step.

See also the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more debugging tips.

---

Further reading:

- [How does argument passing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395743/how-does-argument-passing-work)
- [How can i pass parameters in assembler x86 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975177/how-can-i-pass-parameters-in-assembler-x86-function-call)